# Sumifs return #NA when summing a column of formulas

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column (L) of data that is calculated simply =N#*O#/1000. 
In another tab I have another column where I have a sumifs

```
=SUMIFS('SpX_raw'!$L$2:$L$4253,'SpX_raw'!$E$2:$E$4253,LR!$B4,'SpX_raw'!$F$2:$F$4253,LR!$C4).
```

I know everything is correct in this formula because when I have another column of data where I just paste in the data it works but it returns #NA when I try it on this column with formulas. How can I get the sumifs to work as I intend on this calculated column?

Answer (score 0):

The formulas is OK, and it will only return #N/A as a result if at least one of the combinations it searches for has #N/A in column `L`.

```
=SUMIFS( SpX_raw!$L$2:$L$4253,
SpX_raw!$E$2:$E$4253, LR!$B4,
SpX_raw!$F$2:$F$4253, LR!$C4 )
```

To validate this filter your data in worksheet `SpX_raw` columns `E` and `F` with the values in worksheet `LR` cells `B4` and `C4` respectively and see the corresponding values in worksheet `SpX_raw` column `L`, at least one of them is #N/A